# Histogram is not plotting the full array

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, request, subplot

I am working on python code to insert an area into a histogram. However, the histogram is not plotting the full array being presented. I tested the array to find out why this occurring by printing both the arrays. The result ends up being accurate for the information, but not in comparison to the data array. Here are the arrays:

['Farmington', 'Gallup', 'Grants', 'Las Vegas', 'Raton', 'Santa Fe', 'Taos', 'Tijeras', 'Tucumcari']

[0.002, 0, 0, 0.008, 0.225, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]

The chart only outputs Gallup through SantaFe along with 8 for Gallup and 1 for SantaFe.
Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rainhist = [0.002, 0, 0, 0.008, 0.225, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
cityhist = ['Farmington', 'Gallup', 'Grants', 'Las Vegas', 'Raton', 'Santa Fe', 'Taos', 'Tijeras', 'Tucumcari']
print(cityhist)
print(rainhist)
table = plt.subplot()
table.hist(rainhist, bins=10)
table.set_title("New Mexico North")
table.set_xlabel("Areas")
table.set_ylabel("Accumulation (in.)")
table.set_xticklabels(cityhist, rotation_mode="anchor")
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is the shortest code. I could think of. How would you shorten the code or would you not include the code altogether?

Comment: Thank you on the update.

Comment: If they use the API. I will loose the API access since there is a maximal amount.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144947/discussion-between-drew-bennett-and-importanceofbeingernest).

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Yes, now having a [mcve] available one can actually help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to interprete the histogram differently:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rainhist = [0.002, 0, 0, 0.008, 0.225, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
cityhist = ['Farmington', 'Gallup', 'Grants', 'Las Vegas', 'Raton', 
            'Santa Fe', 'Taos', 'Tijeras', 'Tucumcari']
table = plt.subplot()
table.hist(rainhist, bins=10)
table.set_title("New Mexico North")
table.set_ylabel("Number of areas")
table.set_xlabel("Accumulation (in.)")
plt.show()
```

[image]

There are 8 areas, where precipitation is between 0 and 0.0225 in. And there is one place (Raton) where precipitation is between 0.2025 and 0.225.

It could be that the values in `rainhist` **are** already the values to show as bars. You could then simply plot them without histogramming them again.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rainhist = [0.002, 0, 0, 0.008, 0.225, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
cityhist = ['Farmington', 'Gallup', 'Grants', 'Las Vegas', 'Raton', 
            'Santa Fe', 'Taos', 'Tijeras', 'Tucumcari']
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.bar(range(len(rainhist)), rainhist)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(rainhist)))
ax.set_xticklabels(cityhist, rotation=90)
ax.set_ylabel("Accumulation (in.)")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]